# How to open an input file programmatically (javascript) in a reliably way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

**How to open an input file programmatically (javascript) in a reliably way?**

The most modern versions of internet browsers prevent the opening of input files programmatically (javascript) under certain circumstances. For this reason I opened this thread to define a way to open input files so that we have no problems - or at least mitigate that risk - in future versions of internet browsers.

---

**PLUS:**

**Some statements made in foruns (see references):**

1

> Yes, you can programmatically click the input element using jQuery
>   (JavaScript), but only if you do it in an event handler belonging to
>   an event THAT WAS STARTED BY THE USER.

2

> The function must be part of a user activation such as a click event.
>   Attempting to open the file dialog without user activation will fail.

**A little example (for illustration only):**

Notice the comments in the code.

Apparently the safest way to open an input file is create this element dynamically.

We also have the approach using `.trigger("click")` (worked) and `.click()` (did not work). I couldn't understand why trigger worked and click didn't, because apparently they do the same thing.

**IMPORTANT:** For me there is no guarantee that the "trigger" solution will continue to work in future versions of "Chrome" or even other "browsers" like "Firefox". That is why I think it is important to find a safe way to resolve this issue.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openInputFile() {

        // APPROACH 1 - Didn't work for me ("Chrome").
        $(JQ_TO_FIND_INPUT_FILE).click();

        // APPROACH 2 - Worked for me ("Chrome").
        $(JQ_TO_FIND_INPUT_FILE).trigger("click");

        // APPROACH 3 - Worked for me ("Chrome").
        var inputFile = $('<input type="file"/>');
        $(JQ_TO_FIND_A).after(inputFile);
        inputFile.click();

    }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="openInputFile('theFile');">OPEN FILE DIALOG</a>
    <input type="file"/>
```

[**Refs.:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174934/3223785 , 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583865/3223785 , 
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/programmatically-opening-a-file-dialog-with-javascript , 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/jquery-trigger-click-event-not-the-same-as-a-real-click/170745/3 ]

Comment: Greetings, this question is not a good fit for CodeReview as you are not asking for a code review. I am pretty sure this will get closed as off topic.

Comment: Why use jQuery and all its excessive overheads when input elements have native click method  `document.querySelector("input").click();`